# Typescript - Object value dynamically assign base on Enum key

Tags: typescript, enums

i have put [this code in the TS playground too, click here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAggcgSQLIwDIGUoG8BQUoDCMAKlALxQDkAxgIYAulANHlKggPJzlUA2AlgHsQzVgAUYAJUkdSFSgAdaAJ2WDGLfOgASUgNI9KAZwAWKgNaitcGAlSGjIWv16UcAXxw5%20IesGUAZrTUwFD8AEK0RsAwIPwQtLzYrE4QwABcUEb0yj4A5ppQeaAAJv6ZlAm8wJRQAD5UAcBVNawA7i4lmQBGgoLVtCAeXj5%20gcGh-OhmyuZQwAAefiAlRmGR0bHxicn4CQsA%20nkuvEaZ4BDd-sPevv5BIWFiKmr080ulaxFRMXFVu1AOiA8pksFBWPhqsD6CZMgBGABMAAZCvgwHF6BVqBA3PhPJ4cAB6QlQAAiXAAolAOAA3fxtXL0ej5KAKNQKfz0ACegJMoHeyxKLO6P1Z7LWHRh1Ig-HotzGD0m6CcLgFn2lsoAPN9Nn9EkwqMUVv5KAA%20AFGsrKCp85QJBQmNRCvxuAmje4TMJbKprXD4QbbU6giFQYlkylQCkXKA0xJgYBrKJQczALkhsNiClwUkIOAAcUBtB59EEYTuygU-QYoTZgg5yjLCs9sd48agIuiUGEUBhoVAkGTqZDAG0UzyfLBECgMABdTI636B1juQoZrM5-OF4ul4pvKMDlvxxNrdFCEA9rkctYACiM8RcKh7pdHqbLk%20QaHQM-bYDeAUEDYBOi1DMt2SjKLQEAAJSsLu3qJJk14BlUeipuklACMIzBdgooEgGcUCDFyUHkOaNKCPwJQeEAA), hope it helps.

## Object value dynamically assign base on Enum key

I have this `enum Animals` and what i'm trying to accomplish is to get in the `interface iAnimals` each animal `key` with it's associated interface value if any, if not use the  `interface iBaseAnimal` as default one, so in this case `'lion'` will get the `iBaseAnimal` as interface, but `'snail'` key should get `iSnail` same with the `'parrot'`...etc.

Any help would be much appreciated

```js
enum ANIMALS {
  CAT = 'cat',
  LION = 'lion',
  PARROT = 'parrot',
  SHARK = 'shark',
  SNAIL = 'snail'
}

interface iBaseAnimal {
  name: string,
  gender: 'male' | 'female'
  wild: boolean
}

interface iShark extends iBaseAnimal {
  max_gills: number
}

interface iParrot extends iBaseAnimal {
  wing: { 
    length: 120,
    unit: 'cm'
  }
}

// DONE Overwritting property when extending base props with Omit
interface iSnail extends Omit<iBaseAnimal, 'gender'> {
  gender: 'hermaphrodite'
}

interface iAnimals {
  animals: {
    // DONE Enum values as key
    // PENDING way to interpolate proper interface value base on the enum key
    [key in ANIMALS]: iBaseAnimal
  },
  // PENDING way to get Enum values as union types (similar to [key in ANIMALS] but for function param)
  getAnimal: (animalKey:'lion', options: any) => void
}
```

Comment: I don't see how it can be "dynamic" since there's nowhere in the code that associates the enum with the interfaces in the first place; I mean, you have *names* like `iShark` and *values* like `"shark"` or `"SHARK"`, but there is no programmatic connection between names and values.  You'll have to build such a mapping yourself if you want it, maybe like `AnimalMap` as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/N5OXPW).  Does that fully address your question? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Hello @jcalz, thanks for the reply.
I was thinking in some kind of mapping but using the as to attach an interface which should match the enumValue or the enumKey https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as

Otherwise would be fully manually even with the mapping.

Something like if key in Animals = 'shark'  attach the `i${Shark}` interface

Comment: Type names are not string literal types; there is no programmatic connection between an interface *named* `Foo` and the string literal `"Foo"`, so what you're asking for is impossible.  Does that make sense now?

Answer (score 0):

This might not be what you want, but a potential solution is to switch where you define the animals. Instead of defining them in an enum, define them in an interface:

```
// dict of animal name string -> interface
interface IAnimalsDict {
  shark: IShark;
  parrot: IParrot;
  snail: ISnail;
}

// A string literal type for animal names
type SAnimalName = keyof IAnimalsDict;

// util type to get animal interface by animal name
type AnimalFor<TAnimalName extends SAnimalName> = IAnimalsDict[TAnimalName];
```

And this is how it's used and tested:

```
// Testing SAnimalName
const animalName: SAnimalName = 'parrot';
// @ts-expect-error not a SAnimalName string.
const badAnimalName: SAnimalName = 'megatron';
// Testing IAnimalsDict usage.
const shark: IAnimalsDict['shark'] = {
  name: 'Arthur',
  gender: 'male',
  wild: true,
  max_gills: 1,
};
// @ts-expect-error missing max_gills, a required property of IShark.
const shark2: IAnimalsDict['shark'] = {
  name: 'Arthur',
  gender: 'male',
  wild: true,
};

// Usage in a function:
const addAnimal = <TAnimalName extends SAnimalName> (animalKey: TAnimalName, animal: AnimalFor<TAnimalName>) => {
  // ...
}
// Test
addAnimal('snail', {
  name: 'Jordan',
  // @ts-expect-error bad value for `gender` because ISnail requires `'hermaphrodite'`.
  gender: 'unisex',
  wild: true,
});
addAnimal('snail', {
  name: 'Jordan',
  gender: 'hermaphrodite',
  wild: true,
});
```

Run this on [TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJICE4GcIEETAC2cANsgN4BQyyIchEAXMlmFKAOYA01yHEIACbRmAcmIkIo5AB9komBAlTeAd2AlBzAEYB7XZLghKAX0qVQkWIhSoAygAs4UANbIIAD0hCsaTDnwiUgpeYg8AfQ4NEixmEABXQm1oU3NLaHgkNAAFZyhdMHcvAUFfDGw8AgkQmnUQDmZyZF4aSXqwB2YARgAmAAYeGhp4gjAxBEJRXjMzC3AMmzQ7Og0i71LkAHlCYDAAHnKAqtIueX4haFEAPhq+EpF5B2hiAAcHfMFdlVmAeh-kT4IQq6GDIIxBMh0BgsNicZAAWhu6WsSDmVkytkCEiwABFgEDblgnK5mPZiS4ANy8F55Aqk3JQfJgKk0LArEik5ZwDRU37-cHVKEQXzInBA4C6YxgACeLxQdixpAAcvQUABeZAuCDSkFoRUxPFAqmUP7IeJgVYyuXIMC6O6FAXBZEY5DaaVg46Q1WUK0ofUAMV0UD2ABV9SroZ51r4FZ6IxAbhrUPrcfiwABtMNx1UAXWNppDwot9WQsYh8coCElrA95dVzDLEnjyA1ohpjIKoippoAAmAsPDPHKgYOO1BaAUwaXw6qYex6gA6SvVwraOCCGcMBub9XyBgcOBsSVdk3-QusOHJz2pgnxLBwfhLqsgGtE5wuUkpw0Z0Rv1yiHMW1uIUxFwKAOniKBREGO4LigMRlGgtQNC0G0oHiCAYLCSJoliZAuh4Exu3+PsByHCAR2gfJxx2LAsDhbCohIGJTjgZAoAgABHeJgA4wRkBefI5XA91dTJd8nxXFhyR6T9r2-dNf3JACgKoGgQPkMCIKgmDzmEeC91IKQYPUTRmDYDDCPzf4AFV734ZBQCnGARnFSVGGXF8HUEDdPSA0MdzWEoYx3G4AApHRIABpbVmCzOsGFYz1mADIMAuzBgrgAShbG41OQU0FyK1ICyLSh118iEwt-dloOA+t5AAKSDQQjCQmhe37QcPGHMBR2o1112QAA3UgMOQGAg2QAADPToGm10KLgO9bC5VYOO43jhRm0QnigV53l0T5IFEaalxoOaDNEEZgBwDx2uQUzUIszDTCyqkKv1aq2W5Eg6vyjTRGaqBWpAB7LrEPaDo+L4Hqe8z0Nekx3soIA).

This gives you three things:

- A single place where animal names are associated with animal interfaces: (`IAnimalsDict`).
- A type to check animal names: (`SAnimalNames`).
- A convenient utility type for fetching an interface by name: (`AnimalFor`).

And another marginal side benefit that you don't have to use enums! (they suck ;) )